# Adding URL params to link_to of an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying send a user to:

> http://localhost:3000/restaurants/1?cat=Cocktails

While my **show.html.erb** includes this:

```
<%= link_to(@restaurant, :cat => @item.category) do %>
```

It's still linking to

> http://localhost:3000/restaurants/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to(restaurant_url(@restaurant, :cat => @item.category) do %>
```